# what does the num arg means in openssl rand?

Tags: openssl

this is the manual, https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/rand.html

```
openssl rand
Usage: rand [options] num
```

eg.

```
openssl rand -base64 10
70vQA+9ndS9SwA==

openssl rand -hex 10
778e1081bf76842215a8
irb
irb(main):001:0> "778e1081bf76842215a8".length
=> 20
```

the first one `openssl rand -base64 10` means means generates 10 bytes pseudo-random bytes then perform base64 encoding on that output ?

the second one `openssl rand -hex 10`
 means means generates 10 bytes pseudo-random bytes then show it as hex strings ? why the output is 20 chars ?

Comment: `why the output is 20 chars?` one byte needs two hexadecimal characters.

Comment: "why the output is 20 chars ?" - because one byte is encoded as two hex characters.